# relation between gridviews and formview in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, formview

my question is: I want when I select a row in gridview , that record didnt desplay in formview? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Usually these controls work together when we implement Master Detail Scenario

Take a look at this tutorial [Tutorial 10: Master/Detail Using a Selectable Master GridView with a Details DetailView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx)

Take a look at this example [GridView-FormView (Master/Detail) Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/GridViewFormView.aspx)

and here is an video Tutorial  [[Lesson 8:] Working with the GridView and FormView](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/lesson-8-working-with-the-gridview-and-formview)